# How to add and remove active class automatic to navigation in one page layout?

Tags: jquery, css, navigation

I want to add active class to the navbar links automatic when anyone scrolls down the page and the particular navigation section appears in one page layout. The same way when any one scrolls up the page the active class must keep appending to the particular section in nav links. The layout is one page.

I am referencing the Bootstrap website - you can see on the right side the navigation links when you scroll and the section changes it appends its active class automatically.

Reference URL: http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Comment: check http://jsfiddle.net/cpbcu7kf/ or this  http://jsfiddle.net/a41z24ng/28/

Comment: thanks man @Learner. Its working thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a custom attribute to each section of your html documents and set the value of this attribute the id of the navigation link to be displayed active for this section.

```
<section data-navlink="Link1">
...
</section>
<section data-navlink="Link2">
...
</section>
...
```

Now define your navbar like this

```
<ul id="navbar">
     <li id="Link1">My Link 1</li>
     <li id="Link2">My Link 2</li>
     ...
</ul>
```

Now using jquery or javascript bind the mouseover event to all these sections to a function to toggle the active class of nav links as this

```
$('section[data-navlink]').on('mouseover',function(){
     $('.activenav').removeClass('activenav');
     $('li#'+$(this).attr('data-navlink')).addClass('activenav');
});
```

Also css,

```
.activenav{
text-decoration :underline;
color:red;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

[Watch on fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tyy8cLx6/)